# Solving nonlinear equations with four unknown quantities and not knowing the range of variables?

Tags: equation-solving

how to Solve nonlinear equations with four unknown quantities and not knowing the range of variables?

i have tried

```
FindRoot[{Cos[a] + Sin[b] + c + Cos[d] == 1, a + b + c + d == 1, 
  Sin[a] + b + Cos[c] + d == 10, 
  a/b + c + Sin[d] == 0}, {{a, 1}, {b, 1}, {c, 1}, {d, 1}}]
(*FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.*)
```

(*{a -> 0.213835, b -> 2.08897, c -> -1.2883, d -> 1.68433}*)

and i have vertified that it is not the root

Comment: tips,when there are two variables,we can use contourplot,but whar about four?

Comment: For your set of equations, you can eliminate $a$ and $c$ by solving the second and fourth equations, which lets you use `ContourPlot`, e.g. 
`ContourPlot[Evaluate[eq[[{1, 3}]] /. Solve[eq[[{2, 4}]], {a, c}][[1]]], {b, -25, 
  25}, {d, -25, 25}, PlotPoints -> 50]`. But that won't necessarily work for more complicated systems. The resulting plot does suggest why `FindRoot` gets stuck easily.

Comment: @KraZug thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:**

```
eq = {Cos[a] + Sin[b] + c + Cos[d] == 1, a + b + c + d == 1, 
      Sin[a] + b + Cos[c] + d == 10, a/b + c + Sin[d] == 0};

sol = FindRoot[eq, {{a, -2}, {b, 1}, {c, -1/2}, {d, 1/2}}, 
      Method -> "Newton", WorkingPrecision -> 20]


(*{a -> -10.8876252972741612710960865391, 
   b -> 6.03088227475894982722260273210, 
   c -> 2.25204274483105887715660408019, 
   d -> 3.60470027768415256671687972676}*)

eq /. sol
(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

You need only find a good starting values to `FindRoot` function.

How to find good starting values? Maybe to analog: [Brute-force attack-hope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack)

**Method 2:**

```
sol2 = NMinimize[Join[{1, eq}], {a, b, c, d}, Method -> "RandomSearch"]

(* {1., {a -> -10.8876, b -> 6.03088, c -> 2.25204, d -> 3.6047}}*)
```

Comment: what about this?

    cdn = 12/10;d = 42/10000;l = 20*Sqrt[2];rho = 1025;rho1 = 0.97;p = rho1*l;h = 20;v = 20;k = 600;s = l = 20*Sqrt[2];R = 1/2*rho*cdn*d*v^2;
    eq = {(cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + x2) Sinh[(2 p x2)/(
       cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + x2))])/(2 p) - (
     cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + x2) Sinh[(2 p x1)/(
       cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + x2))])/(2 p) == s + ds, (
    cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + 
       x2) (-Cosh[(2 p x1)/(cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + x2))] + 
       Cosh[(2 p x2)/(cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + x2))]))/(2 p) == h, 
    k*ds*Cos[\[Phi]2x] == R*(x2 - x1), 
    x2 - x1 == Sqrt[(s + ds)^2 - h^2]};

Comment: @dcydhb. This is a different case and that's why you should start a new topic(Question).

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175939/36473

Comment: need your help, too. Thank you.