# Solving nonlinear equations with four unknown quantities and the range of variables is very broad

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the nonlinear equations of four unknown variables, all of which have been assigned, and here are the values of the four variables, but they are very broad.

`x1>0 and is about Hundreds`

`x2>x1 and is about Hundreds`

`\[Phi]2x is form 0 to pi/2`

`ds is about form 0 to 10`

```
cdn = 12/10;d = 42/10000;l = 20*Sqrt[2];rho = 1025;rho1 = 0.97;p = rho1*l;h = 20;v = 20;k = 600;s = l = 20*Sqrt[2];R = 1/2*rho*cdn*d*v^2;
eq = {(cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + x2) Sinh[(2 p x2)/(
   cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + x2))])/(2 p) - (
 cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + x2) Sinh[(2 p x1)/(
   cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + x2))])/(2 p) == s + ds, (
cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + 
   x2) (-Cosh[(2 p x1)/(cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + x2))] + 
   Cosh[(2 p x2)/(cdn d rho v^2 (-x1 + x2))]))/(2 p) == h, 
k*ds*Cos[\[Phi]2x] == R*(x2 - x1), 
x2 - x1 == Sqrt[(s + ds)^2 - h^2]};
FindRoot[eq, {{x1, 124}, {x2, 144}, {ds, 10}, {\[Phi]2x, 0.8}}]
(*FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>*)
(*{x1 -> 159.56, x2 -> 181.501, 
 ds -> 11.0113, \[Phi]2x -> 7.38844*10^-8}*)
```

and i Quote one method

```
sol2 = NMinimize[Join[{1, eq}], {x1, x2, ds, \[Phi]2x}, 
  Method -> "RandomSearch"]
(*NMinimize::nosat: Obtained solution does not satisfy the following constraints within Tolerance -> 0.001`: {Sqrt[-400+(20 Power[<<2>>]+ds)^2]+x1-x2==0,5166/5 (-x1+x2)-600 ds Cos[\[Phi]2x]==0,20-37.6589 (-x1+x2) (-Cosh[0.0265541 x1 Power[<<2>>]]+Cosh[(0.0265541 x2)/Plus[<<2>>]])==0,20 Sqrt[2]+ds+37.6589 (-x1+x2) Sinh[(0.0265541 x1)/(Times[<<2>>]+x2)]-37.6589 (-x1+x2) Sinh[(0.0265541 x2)/(Times[<<2>>]+x2)]==0}.*)
(*{1., {x1 -> 0.44975, x2 -> 0.45087, 
  ds -> 0.00235392, \[Phi]2x -> -0.666751}}*)
```

surely it is not the root

Comment: For your set of equations, you can eliminate `x1` and `ds` by solving the third and fourth equations, which lets you use ContourPlot, e.g. `ContourPlot[ Evaluate[eq[[{1, 2}]] /. Solve[eq[[{3, 4}]], {x1, ds}][[1]]], {x2, 0, 1000}, {\[Phi]2x, -100, 100}, PlotPoints -> 50]`. The resulting plot does suggest why FindRoot spit out errors. In `\[Phi]2x is form 0 to pi/2` can't be seen any solution!.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thank you. Maybe it really didn't have a solution.